# Matrix of a Bilinear map

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ and $W$ be finite dimensional vector spaces. Let $B$ and $B'$ be bases for $V$ and $W$ respectively and let $\beta\in \operatorname{Bil}(V\times W,K)$. Show that there is a unique matrix $A_{B,B'}$ such that for all $(v,w)\in V\times W)$
$\beta(v,w)=X_{B}(v)^{T}A_{B,B'}X_{B'}(w)$.

Please any hint?

Comment: Just consider the values $\beta(v,w)$ as $v$ and $w$ range through your bases.

Comment: Could you please explain a bit?